# Use Google places API in Rails project Client Side Only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I need to use the Google Places API in my rails project using gem but Front-End only, I do not need it on server side. I've been searching around but most examples are just in server side.

What I exactly need to do is to fill an input with addresses. When I start typing it should tell me addresses around me.

Please, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some parts of the Places API can be accessed through the ridiculously named [Places Library, Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). The other API is only intended for server side use.

Comment: Setting up a proxy from through your Rails application to the (server side) places API is pretty trivial though if you want to use any of the more advanced features.